# Why can't I delete the tif file after releasing the resources?

Tags: gis, geotools

I want to read bbox of this tiff, after completion I want to delete this tiff, There seems to be an unclosed stream causing the tiff to not be deleted.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("E:\\test\\1\\昂多.tif");
        GeoTiffReader reader = new GeoTiffReader(file);
        GridCoverage2D read = reader.read(null);
        Envelope2D coverageEnvelope = read.getEnvelope2D();
        Rectangle2D bounds2D = coverageEnvelope.getBounds2D();
        double[] bbox = {
                bounds2D.getMinX(), bounds2D.getMinY(),
                bounds2D.getMaxX(), bounds2D.getMaxY()
        };
        for (double v : bbox) {
            System.out.println(v);
        }
        read.dispose(true);
        reader.dispose();
        FileUtils.forceDelete(file);
    }
```

code running result

```
98.408460773
30.078745248
98.460743439
30.115231446
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: E:\test\1\昂多.tif
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2400)
    at cn.gisdata.core.publish.strategyImpl.Test.main(Test.java:37)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

GeoTools GridCoverage2D dispose(boolean force)  api doc

```
public boolean dispose(boolean force)
Provides a hint that a coverage will no longer be accessed from a reference in user space. This method disposes the image only if at least one of the following conditions is true (otherwise this method do nothing):
force is true, or
The underlying image has no sinks.
This safety check helps to prevent the disposal of an image that still used in a JAI operation chain. It doesn't prevent the disposal in every cases however. When unsure about whatever a coverage is still in use or not, it is safer to not invoke this method and rely on the garbage collector instead.

Overrides:
dispose in class AbstractCoverage
Parameters:
force - true for forcing an inconditionnal disposal, or false for performing a conservative disposal. The recommanded value is false.
Returns:
true if this method disposed at least some resources, or false if this method vetoed against the disposal.
Since:
2.4
See Also:
PlanarImage.dispose()
```

Comment: Can the file be deleted if you do not read from the file first? If not, then see: [Problems deleting a file with Java (apache commons io)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977811/problems-deleting-a-file-with-java-apache-commons-io)

Comment: I'm sure it's not the problem, when the program is done, I can delete it manually

Comment: I suspect it's not the issue either. But there may be other processes or libraries associated with your project that are causing the issue? That test will help detect if the issue is with the streams failing to close or something else.

Comment: Your example works fine for me on linux so probably some windows oddity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify the code

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("E:\\test\\1\\昂多.tif");
        GridCoverage2D read = null;
        GeoTiffReader reader = null;
        try (FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)){
            reader = new GeoTiffReader(is);
            read = reader.read(null);
            Envelope2D coverageEnvelope = read.getEnvelope2D();
            Rectangle2D bounds2D = coverageEnvelope.getBounds2D();
            double[] bbox = {
                    bounds2D.getMinX(), bounds2D.getMinY(),
                    bounds2D.getMaxX(), bounds2D.getMaxY()
            };
            for (double v : bbox) {
                System.out.println(v);
            }
        }finally {
            read.dispose(true);
            reader.dispose();
            FileUtils.forceDelete(file);
        }

    }
```

code running result

```
98.408460773
30.078745248
98.460743439
30.115231446

Process finished with exit code 0
```

GeoTiffReader construction method accept inputStream, So this input stream is controlled by me to close

```java
if (this.source instanceof InputStream || this.source instanceof ImageInputStream) {
                this.closeMe = false;
            }
```